# Упрощение конструктора из C++17

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++20

У меня есть некоторый класс `A` и следующее определение конструктора класса `B`:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, A>, int> = 42>
B(T&& a) : a{std::forward<T>(a)} {}
```

**Как я могу переписать это проще в `C++20`?**

Достаточно ли следующего варианта?

```
template<std::convertible_to<A> T>
B(T&& a) : a{std::forward<T>(a)} {}
```

Или надо что-то такое?

```
template<typename T>
requires std::convertible_to<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, A>
B(T&& a) : a{std::forward<T>(a)} {}
```

Нужен ли `std::remove_cvref_t<T>` в `C++17` варианте?

Comment: Для начала поясните, что вы подразумеваете под "проще" в данном случае.

Comment: @user7860670 наблюдаемое поведение такое же, но запись короче и/или понятнее

Comment: Проще было бы, если бы требования для параметра шаблона выводились бы из содержимого шаблона, а так будет по сути дублирование. А использование концептов добавляет еще один уровень усложнения, хотя запись получается несколько короче.

Comment: А зачем вам вообще `remove_cvref_t`? Мне кажется он лишний.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я портирую чужой код в C++20. Если он тут лишний, то с радостью уберу

Comment: @user7860670 не понял, о каком дублировании речь. Требование к параметру шаблона написано явно и используется он только для конструкции объекта класса `A`. Если вы имеете в виду, что надо просто убрать `std::enable_if_t`, то ошибка будет возникать при неправильном инстанцировании, но только на уровень ниже - в реализации конструктора, а не в определении.

Comment: Я про "Требование к параметру шаблона написано явно" - в теории ничего не мешает выводить его из тела шаблона, а не писать явно. Шаблоны + концепты страдают от проблемы, аналогичной спецификатору noexcept: `foo(X a, X b) noexcept(noexcept(a = b)) { a = b; }`, а в случае с шаблоном и концептом получается что-то вроде `template<typename X> void foo(X a, X b) requires requires{ a = b; } { a = b; }` В ваших вариантах вы используете именованный концепт из библиотеки вместо написания ad hoc требования, но по сути это такое же дублирование тела шаблона, только требующее больше усилий от компилятора.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`remove_cvref_t` лишний в обоих случаях. Вот пример, где он только мешает:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct A
{
    A(int &) {}
};

struct B
{
    A a;
    // Работает:
    // template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T,A>, int> = 42>
    // Не работает:
    template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>,A>, int> = 42>
    B(T&& a) : a{std::forward<T>(a)} {}
};

int main()
{
    int x;
    B b(x); // error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'B'
}
```

Поэтому:

> Достаточно ли следующего варианта?
>
> ```
> template <std::convertible_to<A> T>
> B(T &&a) : a{std::forward<T>(a)} {}
> ```

Да, достаточно.

---

Еще, меня смущает `a{...}` вместо `a(...)`. Пример:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct A
{
    A(int) {}
};

struct B
{
    A a;
    template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T, A>, int> = 42>
    B(T&& a) : a{std::forward<T>(a)} {}
};

int main()
{
    B b((long long)42);
}
```

Здесь `is_convertible_v` возвращает `true` (`convertible_to` сделал бы то же самое), но `a{...}` не компилируется с ошибкой:

```
error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'long long' to 'int' in
  initializer list
```

---

Еще, стоит использовать `is_constructible`/`constructible_from` вместо `is_convertible`/`convertible_to`. Последний требует, чтобы существовало неявное преобразование, но вам достаточно явного.

Пример, когда это создает проблему:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct A
{
    explicit A(int) {}
};

struct B
{
    A a;
    template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T, A>, int> = 42>
    B(T&& a) : a{std::forward<T>(a)} {}
};

int main()
{
    B b(42); // error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'B'
}
```

И тогда еще по-хорошему стоит навесить условный `explicit` (так делает конструктор `std::optional`, например), вот так:

```
template <typename T>
requires std::constructible_from<A, T>
explicit(!std::convertible_to<T, A>)
B(T &&a) : a(std::forward<T>(a)) {}
```